# How can I study the relationship between these two variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis

I am trying to analyse the relationship between unemployment rate and crime rate across 9 regions in England.

Here's what the faceted graph for each region looks like (yes, scaling that unemployment rate line is a pain):

[image]

I was wondering how I can analyse said relationship other than from a "visual" perspective? I.e. it appears that crime rate for Theft decreases as unemployment rate increases, and the opposite is true for Anti-social behaviour related crimes.

This is more a data analysis question rather than a programming one, however all my plots and analyses should be carried out in R, hence why I am posting here.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Plot code:

```
  ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime),
            size = 1, data = crime_data) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(Date, y = rescale(Unemployment.rate, to = out_range, from = in_range),
                          linetype = "Unemployment rate"),
            col = "black", size = 1, data = unemployment_data) +
  labs(linetype = "Unemployment") +
  facet_wrap(~Region,
             scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = 
                       sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range), 
                                name = "Unemployment Rate (%)")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

EDIT: here is a sample of the data I used

**df1 = Crime data**

```
structure(list(
Region = c("London", "South West", "North East", 
  "South West", "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", "London", 
  "South East", "Yorkshire and The Humber", "London", "East of England", 
  "London", "West Midlands", "East of England", "East Midlands", 
  "East of England", "London", "South West", "East Midlands", "North West"
  ), 
Date = structure(c(18078, 18262, 18475, 18078, 17897, 17897, 
  18444, 18231, 17928, 18506, 18201, 18293, 18475, 18201, 18262, 
  18536, 18353, 18414, 18109, 18383), class = "Date"), 
Crime = c("Robbery", 
  "Theft", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", "Violence and sexual 
  offences", "Anti-social behaviour", "Burglary", "Robbery", "Burglary", 
  "Robbery", 
  "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
  "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", "Robbery", "Burglary", 
  "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences"), 
Crime_occurrencies = c(3330L, 
  5508L, 95L, 8427L, 14350L, 15072L, 4942L, 565L, 4569L, 2605L, 
  8375L, 30039L, 7057L, 12141L, 174L, 12854L, 1101L, 987L, 175L, 
  13325L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

**df2 = Unemployment data**

```
structure(list(
Date = structure(c(18170, 18293, 18170, 18201, 
  18475, 17956, 17956, 18078, 18201, 18078, 18140, 18170, 18322, 
  18201, 18383, 18109, 18383, 18048, 17897, 18536), class = "Date"), 
Region = structure(c(8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
  10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L), 
.Label = c("England", 
    "South East", "South West", "London", "East of England", 
    "East Midlands", "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
    "North East", "North West"), class = "factor"), 
Unemployment.rate = c(4.08974888999112, 
    4.71840892982655, 6.11361138828401, 2.8428439676314, 4.13354432440967, 
    4.02517515965457, 5.41295614949722, 4.97071907922267, 4.1730633389162, 
    4.29820710838942, 3.90122545742185, 4.50615604436695, 2.90903701310954, 
    6.21086689536757, 3.79490967669574, 2.38897367671231, 3.97182605242641, 
    4.54049887070026, 4.68247349426148, 3.86912441545878)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

**GEOM SMOOTH OUTPUTS**
When run before geom_line:

[image]

When run on its own:

[image]

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend', group=1),
              data=crime_count)
```

Comment: Hi dear. It would be fine if you add the data you used for the plot. There are plenty of ways to reach what you want!

Comment: Hello boss! I updated the post with the a sample of the original data. The crime dataset is especially big, so I am not sure how much you can make out of a small sample (20 rows). Hope it helps!

Comment: Please also add the code for your magnificent plot!

Comment: Sorry, just added that too!

Comment: Please what are the values for `to = in_range, from = out_range`

Comment: `out_range <- range(crime_data$Crime_occurrencies)` and
`in_range <- range(unemployment_data$Unemployment.rate)` . The values are: out range = [1] 49 and [2] 20000 (I set this one manually for scaling purposes); in range = [1] 2.350958 and
[2] 6.670885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with `geom_smooth()`. Here, I have used to create a trend for crime so that you can compare with the other variable and derive relationships:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Values
out_range <- range(crime_data$Crime_occurrencies)
in_range <- range(unemployment_data$Unemployment.rate)
#Plot
ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime),
            size = 1, data = crime_data) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(Date, y = rescale(Unemployment.rate, to = out_range,
                                            from = in_range),
                          linetype = "Unemployment rate"),
            col = "black", size = 1, data = unemployment_data) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend'),
              data=crime_data)+
  labs(linetype = "Unemployment") +
  facet_wrap(~Region,
             scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = 
                       sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range), 
                                name = "Unemployment Rate (%)")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

With your full data you can get the complete trend, and if necessary, you can add `group=1` inside `aes()` from `geom_smooth()`.

Comment: Woow I have no idea what geom_smooth is but it seems really useful, thanks for doing all that! I tried running it and I got a " `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x' " Error, I am googling to find out how to fix it right now. P.s. I tried with and without grou=1, same error

Comment: @Lactuca Try adding the data argument inside it as well as the x and y values

Comment: The x and y values are already inside it, which data arguments are you referring to?  From the first or the second geom_line()? `geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend', group=1), data=crime_count)+`

Comment: @Lactuca Yeah you are right, some typo maybe

Comment: Not sure why it works for you though, I literally copy pasted the code. Anyway thanks for trying!

Comment: It just says " geom_smooth() using formula 'y ~ x' ". And then the plot appears completely blank

Comment: Try placing the smooth code in the end of all code

Comment: I tried putting it at the end of everything (i.e. after theme() ), in the middle (i.e. after facet_wrap() and then after scale_y_continuous() ) but I get the same error and blank output. I found someone who had a similar  issue on another forum but his df was too different from mine to have the same solution

Comment: @Lactuca Try placing at the beginning! And only run the smooth part!

Comment: Ok it works if I place it before geom_line!! It's that blue line right? I am guessing that the more steep it is, the stronger the positive / negative relationship between crime rate and unemployment rate? P.s. you deserve a place in programming heaven

Comment: @Lactuca Yeah, you are right about the conclusions. Nice, so it worked, right?

Comment: @Lactuca Always a pleasure helping you :)

Comment: One last question if I may! Is there any way I can add a legend called "Smoothed conditional mean" to geom_smooth()? I tried doing what I did for unemployment rate, i.e.  `linetype = "pretty name"` and then at the end `labs(linetype="pretty name")` but when I do it in geom_smooth() it renames the unemployment rate legend to "trendline" :s

Comment: @Lactuca Did you add that inside `aes()`? In that case geom_smooth(aes(...,linetype='myline')) would work!

Comment: I ran this inside aes() and it shows the same plot as always,but renaming the "unemployment" legend `geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, lty = 6, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend', linetype="Smoothed conditional mean"), data=crime_count)+ labs(linetype = "Smoothed conditional mean")`

Comment: Try placing outside aes this piece `lty=2` and remove the linetype inside aes!

Comment: You mean like this? It won't let me plot anything, I get an error message saying "Cannot add ggproto objects together"  `geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend'), lty=2 + data=crime_count)+`

Comment: Strange, let me check a moment!

Comment: Try this `geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,color='Trend'), lty=2,data=crime_count)+`

Comment: Or this: `geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrencies,linetype='Trend'),data=crime_count)+`

Comment: The second option works a charm! It changes the Unemployment rate line to a dashed one though, and I'd rather have the smoothed conditional mean as a dashed line. When I try to add lty=6 inside or outside of aes() it won't change it though, am I doing anything (esle) wrong?

Comment: You can use `scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,6))` at the end to change the format!

Comment: Jesus you're a genius, thanks a gain you life saver!

Comment: @Lactuca Just a person helping others! If interested in any training let me know or check my stackoverflow for more details :) Kind regards!

Comment: I think I'm gonna definitely need it at some point ^^" I've just noticed that in the legend, the Unemployment rate is now blue though, even though in the graph it's black. I always specified col = "black" ? I tried adding col = "black" all over the Unemployment data geom_line() but the legend stays blue for some reason T_T

Comment: @Lactuca Try adding the `color='black'` outside aes() or use `scale_color_manual()` but you would have the number of colors related to how many lines you have!

Comment: It's already outside, it won't let me add it inside  `geom_line(mapping = aes(Date, y = rescale(Unemployment.rate, to = out_range, from = in_range), linetype = "Unemployment rate"), col = "black", size = 1, data = unemployment_data) + labs(linetype = " ") +` I left labs(linetype = " ") because there's no point in adding a legend title for the unemployment rate and the smoothed conditional mean

Comment: It only changes the colour of the "first" legend (i.e. the one under "Crime"). However it won't let me change the colour of Smooth Conditional Mean and Unemployment Rate (neither in the graph nor in their legend). I added it right before theme() `scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "Anti-social behaviour" = "red", 
    "Burglary" = "green", 
    "Robbery" = "darkgreen",
    "Theft" = "orange",
    "Violence and sexual offences" = "purple",
    "Smoothed Conditional Mean" = "pink",
    "Unemployment rate" = "black")) +`

Comment: Maybe is because of `color` being present in first aes(), could you try to add color to the second `geom_line()` as well as `geom_smooth()`? It is a play with options at this stage:)

Comment: Maybe is because of `color` being present in first aes(), could you try to add color to the second `geom_line()` as well as `geom_smooth()`? It is a play with options at this stage:)

Comment: Ok! The second geom_line is the unemployment one, which already has `col = "black"`. I added a `col =` in `geom_smooth`, and apparently whichever colour I add in `geom_smooth()` ends up colouring *the whole unnamed legend* (i.e. the dashed mean and the unemployment rate). However, it does not change the colour of the unemployment rate IN the graph. To change that, I have to change col = in its `geom_line()`. I tried adding `scale_colour_manual()` in `geom_smooth()`, but it only recognises 5 variables (i.e. the crime types under the "Crime" legend).

Comment: the manual option is outside, as a new element in the plot!

Comment: Yeah but even if I add it outside, like I did before when I added it before theme(), it still won't change the colour of the unnamed legend elements. Hence why I tried adding inside geom_smooth(); it was out of desperation ahha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227227/discussion-between-lactuca-and-duck).